# Running Cassandra in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra in my windows environment, I run it with cassandra.bat.

Now, I have an Spring Boot application that contains the following cassandra configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.manuel.cassandra.repositories")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "testKeySpace";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9142);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() { return false; }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new CassandraMappingContext();
    }

}
```

But I can't run the application because I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Session
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.Session
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

These are my cassandra related dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
implementation 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:4.0.0'
implementation 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jmx:4.1.0'
```

My application.yml file is empty and I also have declared a repository, but I think the error isn't related to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` depends on the `sprint-data-cassandra` that uses Java driver 3.6.0, and you have specified the dependency on the 4.0.0 - this version is not binary compatible with 3.x releases, so you need to correct your dependencies.